# UnauthorizedAccessException in visual studio design view

Tags: c#, telerik, windows-store-apps, visual-studio-2013, windows-8.1

I am having a problem with the design view of visual studio where I will get an error when I try to load a `Telerik` reference specifically `Telerik controls for windows 8` when I load that I get the exception when I remove it the exception goes away.

all this happens on a blank `xaml` with only a grid in it. The project will run fine and show whatever UI I have in the xaml but it just wont show in the design view.

this is the stack trace

```
    System.UnauthorizedAccessException
Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Silverlight.AssemblyMetadataHelper.IMetaDataDispenserEx.OpenScope(String szScope, Int32 dwOpenFlags, Guid& riid)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Silverlight.AssemblyMetadataHelper.OpenScope(IMetaDataDispenserEx dispenser, String path)
   at Microsoft.Expression.Utility.AssemblyHelper.TryGetAttributeValueAsString(String path, String attributeName, String& attributeValue, Boolean& attributeExists)
   at Microsoft.Expression.Utility.AssemblyHelper.IsDesignAssembly(String path, Version extensibilityAssemblyVersion)
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignSurface.Assemblies.ProjectAssemblyResolver.FindBestMetadataAssembly(IEnumerable`1 possiblePaths)
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignSurface.Assemblies.ProjectAssemblyResolver.FindMetadataAssembly(String assemblyPath, String designerExtension)
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignSurface.Assemblies.ProjectAssemblyResolver.EnsureDesignMetadataLoaded(Boolean showErrors)
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignSurface.Assemblies.ProjectAssemblyResolver.AssemblyCollection_EnumerationChanged(Object sender, EnumerationChangedEventArgs`1 e)
   at System.EventHandler`1.Invoke(Object sender, TEventArgs e)
   at Microsoft.Expression.Utility.Collections.NotifyingCollectionBase`1.EventInvoker(EnumerationChangedEventArgs`1 eventArguments)
   at Microsoft.Expression.Utility.Events.SuspendingEventManager`1.ForwardEvents()
   at Microsoft.Expression.Utility.Events.Suspender.SuspendDisposer.Dispose(Boolean disposing)
   at Microsoft.Expression.Utility.Events.Suspender.SuspendDisposer.Dispose()
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignSurface.Assemblies.AssemblyCollection.AssemblyService_AssembliesUpdated(Object sender, EventArgs`1 e)
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignSurface.Assemblies.AssemblyService.OnAssembliesUpdated(IEnumerable`1 assemblyInformation)
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignSurface.Assemblies.AssemblyService.WindowsRuntimeService_IterationContextChanged(Object sender, WindowsRuntimeContextChangedEventArgs e)
   at System.EventHandler`1.Invoke(Object sender, TEventArgs e)
   at Microsoft.Expression.Utility.WindowsRuntimeService.SetIterationContext(String[] paths)
   at Microsoft.Expression.Utility.WindowsRuntimeService.SynchronizeDesignerContext()
   at Microsoft.Expression.Utility.WindowsRuntimeService.ProcessShadowCopyResults(IEnumerable`1 results)
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignSurface.Assemblies.AssemblyService.FlushShadowCopyUpdateQueue()
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignSurface.Assemblies.ProjectAssemblyResolver.Project_ReferencesChanged(Object sender, HostItemChangesEventArgs`1 e)
   at System.EventHandler`1.Invoke(Object sender, TEventArgs e)
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.LocalEvent`3.<>c__DisplayClass1b.<Invoke>b__1a()
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.STAMarshaler.Call.InvokeWorker()
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.STAMarshaler.Call.Invoke(Boolean waitingInExternalCall)
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.STAMarshaler.InvokeCall(Call call)
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.STAMarshaler.DirectInvoke(Boolean inbound, Action action, Int32 sourceApartmentId, Int32 targetApartmentId, Int32 originId, WaitHandle aborted)
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.STAMarshaler.DirectInvokeInbound(Action action, Int32 targetApartmentId)
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.STAMarshaler.MarshalIn(Action action, Int32 targetApartmentId, CancellationToken cancelToken, CallSynchronizationMode syncMode, CallModality callModality, String methodName, String filePath, Int32 lineNumber)
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.ThreadMarshaler.MarshalIn(IRemoteObject targetObject, Action action, CallSynchronizationMode syncMode, CallModality callModality, ApartmentState apartmentState, String memberName, String filePath, Int32 lineNumber)
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.LocalEvent`3.Invoke(Object sender, TEvent args)
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.LocalHostProject.<>c__DisplayClass9b.<Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.IRemoteHostProjectCallback.OnReferencesChanged>b__9a()
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.STAMarshaler.Call.InvokeWorker()
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.STAMarshaler.Call.Invoke(Boolean waitingInExternalCall)
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.STAMarshaler.InvokeCall(Call call)
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.STAMarshaler.ProcessQueue(CallQueue queue)
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.STAMarshaler.ProcessInboundQueue(Int32 identity)
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.STAMarshaler.ProcessMessage(Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean elevatedQuery, Boolean& handled)
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.STAMarshaler.OnWindowMessage(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.MessageOnlyHwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
   at MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(MSG& msg)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(DispatcherFrame frame)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrame(DispatcherFrame frame)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Run()
   at System.Windows.Application.RunDispatcher(Object ignore)
   at System.Windows.Application.RunInternal(Window window)
   at System.Windows.Application.Run(Window window)
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.DesignerProcess.RunApplication()
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.DesignerProcess.DesignProcessViewProvider.AppContainerDesignerProcessRun(String[] activationContextArgs)
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.DesignerProcess.DesignProcessViewProvider.<>c__DisplayClass7.<applicationView_Activated>b__6()
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
```

and my `xaml`

```
    <Page  
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:t3"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:Input="using:Telerik.UI.Xaml.Controls.Input"
    x:Class="t3.MainPage"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        <Button Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="517,180,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

the error really does not seem to give me any information on what the problem is. Any ideas?